# Vector of Vectors. Remove duplicates based on specific index of inner vectors

Tags: c++, vector, unique, combinations, permutation

I have been using a combination of different variables and data structures for this, I am not sure which is best in practice. I don't care much how long it takes to run these calculations, I just care about the end result.

I have a combination of values. V - W - X - Y : Z. V,W,X, and Y are used to calculate Z. V, W, X, and Y each have 256 different possibilities. So I believe I am working with a combination.

V - W - X - Y : Z

So long as all my values are the same, the order doesn't matter, I still get the same result.

---

0 - 52 - 115 - 249 : 0.059784

52 - 249 - 0 - 114 : 0.059784

249 - 52 - 114 - 0 : 0.059784

---

0 - 52 - 115 - 250 : 0.057423

0 - 250 - 115 - 52 : 0.057423

250 - 0 - 52 - 115 : 0.057423

---

0 - 52 - 115 - 251 : 0.055006

115 - 251 - 52 - 0 : 0.055006

251 - 0 - 52 - 115 : 0.055006

---

I need my end result to be a list of these values that are unique to Z. I don't really care which combination gets saved to achieve said unique value for Z. I just need to retain the value of Z which is a float (though in the end result I can store it as a string I suppose), and the values of V, W, X, Y.

So if I start with this:

250 - 0 - 52 - 115 : 0.057423

0 - 52 - 115 - 249 : 0.059784

0 - 52 - 115 - 250 : 0.057423

52 - 249 - 0 - 114 : 0.059784

0 - 52 - 115 - 251 : 0.055006

0 - 250 - 115 - 52 : 0.057423

251 - 0 - 52 - 115 : 0.055006

249 - 52 - 114 - 0 : 0.059784

115 - 251 - 52 - 0 : 0.055006

---

I would end with something similar to this:

250 - 0 - 52 - 115 : 0.057423

0 - 52 - 115 - 249 : 0.059784

115 - 251 - 52 - 0 : 0.055006

---

Any help/advice would be appreciated. Many thanks!

---

EDIT: Adding more to this to help decipher some issues.

So the idea of the entire project I am working on is to calculate every possible resistance for a quad digital potentiometer when you wire each of the four potentiometers in parallel. I may calculate series later, but for right now parallel is what I am after.

The potentiometer itself has an A terminal, B terminal, and Wiper terminal. We are looking for the resistance between the A terminal and the wiper terminal.

This is a 1k ohm 8 bit potentiometer. That means we have 256 steps of resolution to work with. To calculate the resistance for a certain step, we figure out:

```
trim = (((( (ohmRatingOfDigiPot)*(numberofPossibleSteps - stepToCalculate) )/numberofPOssileSteps)+wiperResistance)/1000);
```

So, our equation turns out to be

```
trim  = (((( (1000)*(256-index) )/256)+50)/1000)
```

Where `index` is the step (out of 256 total steps) we are on.

So I figure out the possible values of each of these steps and I pass them into an array. One for each of the four potentiometers in the quad potentiometer.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    trim  = (((( (1000)*(256-index) )/256)+50)/1000);
    index++;
    potOneSteps[i] = trim;
    potTwoSteps[i] = trim;
    potThreeSteps[i] = trim;
    potFourSteps[i] = trim;
}
```

Yes, I know there is probably a much better way to do that. Like I said, it has been so long since I've used C++. This worked and I knew I had other things to worry about so it ended up staying. Ha.

So now I need to figure out every possible value for these four potentiometers in every different combination available. 4 potentiometers with 256 possible value for each? Bring on the for loops!

To calculate the resistance of resistors in parallel, we use:

```
Total Resistance = ( 1 / ( (1/R1) + (1/R2) + (1/R3) + ... + (1/Rn))
```

For our four arrays I figured this:

```
for (int A1W1 = 0; A1W1 < 256; A1W1++)
{
    for (int A2W2 = 0; A2W2 < 256; A2W2++)
    {
        for (int A3W3 = 0; A3W3 < 256; A3W3++)
        {
            for (int A4W4 = 0; A4W4 < 256; A4W4++)
            {
                rTrim = (1/((1/potOneSteps[A1W1]) + (1/potTwoSteps[A2W2]) + (1/potThreeSteps[A3W3]) + (1/potFourSteps[A4W4])));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Very long. Very processor and memory intensive. Very poor. I know. I know.

This was the only way I could think to go through all of the values to do the calculations. Not sure if there is a better way, open to any and all suggestions.

So in my original post, V - W - Y - X correspond with the index where Z was calculated. And Z is the the actual resistance that we calculated using the values at said indices. Since all of the arrays are the same we get repeat values like I spoke about in the original post. So I only need to know the unique values for Z/rTrim and the step(s) at which it was found in order to have all of the possible values and be able to set the digital pots to said values.

I am open to any and all variables/data structures/etc for this. Nothing really has to be set to a certain type so I can deal with doubles, floats, ints, arrays, vectors, sets, linked lists (oh please no!), etc.

I hope that makes sense. Kind of long winded but I figured it would be beneficial to have all of the information available for what I am trying to go for. Many thanks!!

---

EDIT2:

I may have solved this problem with PHP and mySQL, my "native" languages. If you guys still want to lend a hand, I am all ears and willing to learn best practices, but don't feel obligated. Much appreciated for the help you did provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1) define a class that holds the 4 values and the floating point value.

2) Define an `operator <` for this class that compares the floating point value.

3) Define a `std::set` of this class and populate it.

Here is an example:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;

struct MyValueClass
{
    IntVector m_vals;
    double m_finalVal;
    bool operator < (const MyValueClass& c2) const 
    { return (m_finalVal < c2.m_finalVal);  }
    MyValueClass(const IntVector& v, double val) : m_vals(v), m_finalVal(val) {}
};

typedef std::set<MyValueClass> ValueClassSet;

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<MyValueClass> mc;
    // Sample data
    mc.push_back(MyValueClass(IntVector{ 250, 0, 52, 115 }, 0.057423));
    mc.push_back(MyValueClass(IntVector{ 0, 52, 115, 249 }, 0.059784));
    mc.push_back(MyValueClass(IntVector{ 0, 52, 115, 250 }, 0.057423));
    mc.push_back(MyValueClass(IntVector{ 52, 249, 0, 114 }, 0.059784));
    mc.push_back(MyValueClass(IntVector{ 0, 52, 115, 251 }, 0.055006));
    mc.push_back(MyValueClass(IntVector{ 0, 250, 115, 52 }, 0.057423));
    mc.push_back(MyValueClass(IntVector{ 251, 0, 52, 115 }, 0.055006));
    mc.push_back(MyValueClass(IntVector{ 249, 52, 114, 0 }, 0.059784));
    mc.push_back(MyValueClass(IntVector{ 115, 251, 52, 0 }, 0.055006));

    // populate set with sample data from vector
    ValueClassSet ms;
    ValueClassSet::iterator it = ms.begin();
    copy(mc.begin(), mc.end(), inserter(ms, it));

    // output results
    ValueClassSet::iterator it2 = ms.begin();
    while (it2 != ms.end())
    {
        copy(it2->m_vals.begin(), it2->m_vals.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
        cout << " : " << it2->m_finalVal << "\n";
        ++it2;
    }
}

Output:
0 52 115 251  : 0.055006
250 0 52 115  : 0.057423
0 52 115 249  : 0.059784
```

So basically, we populate a vector of your information, and then we populate the `set` with the vector.  Since a `std::set` only stores unique values, only the unique Z items will be stored.  The `operator <` that we set up for the `MyValueClass` type is what `std::set` will use to determine if an item is already in the set.

Note:  I used `C++11` initialization syntax to populate the vector.  If you're using a compiler that is pre C++11, populate the vector the "old-fashioned way".

Comment: one may point out that if the float is really calculated from the 4 byte values, then it may well happen that  you get different floats even though you expect the same value. float as key seems brittle, imo

Comment: @MartinBa - Yes, your point is valid.  I also thought of the calculation of Z, but only posted my answer given that the OP worked out those issues separately.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sir. I am testing right now based on what you've told me. Still getting duplicate values for Z. Looking into it to see if I can see where I went wrong.



@MartinBa I appreciate the input. It has been too long since I've touched C++. Forgive my ignorance. Is there a better option to use? Perhaps double instead of float?

Comment: @karadorde - it all depends on *how* the float is calculated. Post the formula in the question. Oh, and it's got nothing to do with C++ and all with FP :-) ... `double` won't help.

Comment: @MartinBa Ha, of course. I updated the original post with a lot of information. Hopefully that helps to decipher a few things. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

*Edit :*

As I suspected, your problem is not to remove duplicates from an already computed array of values. From what I have understood about your edit, you can simply compute the necessary values without duplicates in the first place.

For instance, imagine two loops in the range 0 to 3 like so :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        someVectorOfPair.push_back(std::make_pair(i, j));
    }
}
```

Here, you will get all the possible ordered pairs of values from 0 to 3. Now, you are looking for all the possible *unordered* pairs, so you consider (0, 1) and (1, 0) duplicates. This is the most straightforward way to do it :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j < 4; ++j) { // Only one character changed
        someVectorOfPair.push_back(std::make_pair(i, j));
    }
}
```

If you start j with the current value of i, you will not compute pairs (x, y) where y < x. However, you will get every other combinations, and it seems that it solves your problem.

Oh, by the way, `(((( (1000)*(256-index) )/256)+50)/1000)` can be written like so : `(256.-i)/256. + 0.05`. I did not understand everything in your calculations, but if i can go backward, you can simplify further : `i/256. + 0.05`. The point is here to do floating-point calculation if `i` is an `int`. You can also cast with `static_cast<double>` (or `float`).

*Original :*

How do you store your data ? How much data do you have ? How do you calculate Z ?

Without the answers to these questions, I can only present a very simple (but not efficient) way to reach your goal : copying your data into another "vector of vector" with duplicate checking. This is roughly how it is done (not tested) :

```
for (itD : data) {
    itR = std::find_if(result.begin(), result.end(), [&itD](result::iterator it) { it.Z == itD.Z });

    if (itR == result.end()) {
        result.push_back(*itD);
    }
}
```

Then again, this is not really efficient. You can also use a set (ordered or not) to store the result : this way, insertion automatically checks for duplicates (since a set have unique keys).

Answer (score 2):

First, let's get the combinatorics right:

Given n items and d possibilities for each item, where `n=4`and `d=256` here, we have:

- Number of combinations if order is important: `d ^ n` and 256^4 is simply 2^32 for 4 x 8 = 32 bit
- If order is *not* important, the [formula](http://www.murderousmaths.co.uk/books/unknownform.htm) is `(n+d-1)! / (d! * (n-1!))` ... `2.862.209` ~ 3M distinct combinations in this case (a lot better that the 4G of the ordered combinations)

However, given the problem of `n` resistors (in parallel or serial), not only is the order not important, but even **the combinations themselves are only important if they yield different *sums***.

- The number of different sums (as opposed to their [probabilities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html)) is trivially `(n * d) - (n - 1)` (With the lowest sum `0 := 0 + 0 + 0 + 0` and the highest `1020 := 255 + ... + 255` for `1021` different sums in this case.

So, what you should do, expanding on [the answer of @PaulMc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25220818/321013), is to define `operator<` in terms of the sum of the 4 values, not their possibly unstable float result.

However, given your for loops from the question, you'd still insert into the set 4G(!) (256^4) times to get your 1021 slots filled.

So, if you already know that the order doesn't matter, fill the set in an efficient manner, and it doesn't matter if you get all combinations, you just need to capture all different sums:

Full example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/582dc32f8d49712e) / the loop:

```
using Combination = std::array<int, n>;

...

std::set<Combination> all;
Combination c{}; // must value initialize a std::array to zero-init its int values
for (int pos = 0; pos != n; ++pos) {
    for (int i = 0; i != d; ++i) {
        c[pos] = i; // c[0] from 0..d (remains at d), then c[1] from 0..d, etc.
        all.insert(c);
    }
}
```